# not able to access values of array list from mainactivity

Tags: android, json, facebook, arraylist

I have program which uses the Facebook Graph API to get the post ids of various posts from a Facebook image.Here is the code I have used for this:

**oncreate()**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variable Declarations
    TextView textView1;
    public  ArrayList<String> postIds = new ArrayList<>();//array to store various post ids
    ArrayList<String> imageIds = new ArrayList<>();//has the various imageURLs
    ImageView img1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getPosts();
        System.out.println("PostIDS value in Main Activity:"+postIds.toString());
        System.out.println("Done Execution From Main Activity");

    }//onCreate
```

Getposts():

```
public void getPosts()
    {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                a,
                "/internationalchaluunion",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        // Insert your code here
                        System.out.println("Response::" + String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
                        JSONObject jsRoot = response.getJSONObject();
                        JSONObject jsArr1 = null;
                        try {
                            jsArr1 = jsRoot.getJSONObject("posts");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        JSONArray arr1 = jsArr1.optJSONArray("data");

                        //iterate JSONArray and store the values to different
                        for(int i=0; i < arr1.length(); i++)
                        {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = arr1.getJSONObject(i);
                                //System.out.println("Id"+i+":"+jsonObject.optString("id"));
                                String str = jsonObject.optString("id");
                                str=str.substring(str.indexOf("_")+1,str.length());
                                postIds.add(str);
                            }//try
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }//catch


                        }//for

                        /
                }//onCompletedMethod
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "posts");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();


    }
```

When i try to access the value of postIDs in getposts() function I can see that all the values are set properly.But when i try to access the postsIds[] from the main method or any other method is the same class postIDs[] is an empty array.Can you tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: are you ensuring that the request has completed before trying to access it from another method?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, we can confirm that you are executing an Async call for getting the required data in ***getPosts();***

It is a good practice to use the fetched data in ***onComplete()*** callback whenever possible, since you never know how long the async task would execute - as it depends on Network/Processor/Heavy computation if present internally.

Check this [example](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) generic AsyncTask in Android